# Android Studio java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have several problems.

1. The application does not run because of a NullPointerException.

> Error content: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference

**Activity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView navView;
RecyclerView myContactsList;
ImageView findPeopleBtn;

private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStage) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStage);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

    navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);

    findPeopleBtn = findViewById(R.id.find_people_btn);
    myContactsList = findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
    myContactsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));  =>error

    findPeopleBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent findPeopleIntent = new Intent(ContactsActivity.this,FindPeopleActivity.class);
        startActivity(findPeopleIntent);
    });
}
```

**activity.xml**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/contact_list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout_contacts"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

2. Firebase's real-time database cannot be uploaded.

Please refer to the picture below.
[image]

Any advice is good, so please comment.

Comment: My layout is activity_contacts.xml.

Comment: Have you tried changing `getApplicationContext()` to `this` in your `setLayoutManager` line?

Comment: I shouldn't even change it to this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of things wrong with your code.
Firstly your `DatabaseReference` does not reference a child from firebase.

```
private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("NameOfTheNode");
```

Refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

You can then use this child reference and use the FirebaseUI for Realtime Database to provide an easier way to get attach your children to the `RecyclerView`. To find out how to implement this, refer below: https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme/

After creating your `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`, create the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and override the `onCreateViewHolder()` and the `onBindViewHolder()` for your own implementations.

Then set the instance of the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` as the adapter for your recycler view and it will start to read data.

For the problem where your `Realtime Database` has null, try importing a `JSON` file with data in the Firebase Console.

Comment: I need a more detailed explanation.

I'm a beginner...

Can you call me the code in detail..?

Comment: What do you mean by "call me the code in detail"?